# Get latest post for category

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get the latest post for each of the category in my forum app. I've been trying things like `Category.objects.order_by('catID').annotate(latestpost=Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:1])`
I want to be able to do use the values: `postID`, `title`, `user` and `pub_date` in my template.

models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    catID = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Post(models.Model):
    postID = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    catID = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    cats = Category.objects.order_by('catID').annotate(latestpost=Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:1])
    context = {'forum_cats': cats}
    return render(request, 'forums/index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is

```
class Category(models.Model):
    catID = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def latest_post(self):
        post = self.post_set.order_by('-pub_date')
        if post:
            return post[0]
        return None
```

and in the template,

```
{% for cat in forum_cats %}
    {% if cat.latest_post %}
        {{cat.latest_post.title}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Or use the simple `get_latest_by` model meta option described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#get-latest-by)